# Random dates turning into Christmas

Tags: rebus, music, seasonal

These days, I saw a rebus on the net that shows **a calendar of December, with some random dates turning into Christmas**. I feel very puzzled about this. Can you help me?

[image]

Edit: *I found that rebus on Bing.*

Comment: It skipped the CAPTCHA thing.

Comment: they probably weren't random

Comment: I'm afraid we can't help you unless you provide us with the actual rebus. As it stands, you're asking us to solve a puzzle without actually providing us with said puzzle.

Comment: it'slike https://cn.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=52%2bMhkNy&id=403DE462D2ED85ABA8AA23D557B532EA66C1F681&thid=OIP.52-MhkNy2jpC1oMFdXCPRAHaJc&mediaurl=http%3a%2f%2fssqq.com%2farchive%2fimages%2foriginal%2520puzzle%2520fmy%2520950.jpg&exph=1211&expw=950&q=rebus&simid=607989787935180558&selectedIndex=343

Comment: @Scratch---Cat I have edited the picture into the question and nominated for reopening.

Comment: Isn't that just some sort of an advent calendar?

Comment: As the text suggests, each image in the puzzle represents a Christmas carol. For number $16$, count the number of days marked as $25$

Comment: Just saying. In the bottom of the picture, you could see the words got cropped in almost half horizontally. rot13"Ubj jryy qb lbh xabj lbhe pnebyf?"

Comment: I found this which might be useful: https://www.thoughtco.com/top-christmas-songs-3245323. For 8, how about (4) Rock buns around the Christmas Tree

Answer (score 5):

Well it seems to be that,

> These are Christmas carols in a rebus.

1

> Jingle Bells

2

> Walking in a Winter Wonderland

3

> Santa Claus is coming to town

4

> Joy to the World

5

> Rudolph the red nose Reindeer

6

> Come all ye Faithful ([Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78473/random-dates-turning-into-christmas/78488#78488))

7

> I'm Dreaming of a White Christmas

8

> Oh Christmas tree?

9

> What Child is this

10

> We three Kings

11

> Deck the Halls

12

> Little Drummer Boy

13

> O Holy Night([Daniel Mathias](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78473/random-dates-turning-into-christmas/78491#78491))

14

> Noel

15

> Away in a Manger([Daniel Mathias](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78473/random-dates-turning-into-christmas/78491#78491))

16

> 12 Days of Christmas([Daniel Mathias](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78473/random-dates-turning-into-christmas/78491#78491))

17

> I saw Mommy Kissing Santa Claus

18

> All I want for Christmas are my two Front Teeth

19

> Chestnuts Roasting on the Open Fire

20

> It came upon A Midnight

21

> let it Snow?

22

> Silent Night

23

> Oh Little Town of Bethlehem([Daniel Mathias](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78473/random-dates-turning-into-christmas/78491#78491))

24

> Silver Bells([Daniel Mathias](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78473/random-dates-turning-into-christmas/78491#78491))

Answer (score 4):

Partial to get some easy ones out of the way :)

1.

> Jingle Bells

3.

> Santa Claus Is Coming to Town

4.

> Joy to the World

5.

> Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer

6.

> O Come All Ye Faithful

7.

> White Christmas

17.

> I Saw Mommy Kissing Santa Claus

22.

> Silent Night

Answer (score 4):

> 11 is Deck the Halls and 22 is Silent Night.

Comment: Hi Nixel, welcome to Puzzling.  Please use the spoiler tag (">!") when answering

Answer (score 4):

13

> O Holy Night

15

> Away in a Manger

16

> Twelve Days of Christmas

20

> It Came Upon a Midnight Clear

23

> O Little Town of Bethlehem

24

> Silver Bells

Comment: Wow you found some really good ones! +1